# How to integrate InvoiceCreator into the checkout flow

Tags: django, django-oscar

Im following the instructions on how to utilize django-oscar-invoices on https://django-oscar-invoices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html , but I dont understand how to integrate oscar_invoices.utils.InvoiceCreator into the checkout flow.
Can anyone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the sandbox folder of django-oscar-invoice there is a test_app that show how to do what is mentionned in the documentation.